# Selenium alert authentification

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to access a website located on my localhost. When I navigate to it, an alert appears and I have to authenticate, but when I use the method "authenticateUsing", it shows me that it does not exist. Can anyone help me?

```
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("http://localhost:8015/thing/Home");
        String username = "a";
        String password = "bbbbb";
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);      
        Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());     
        alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

The error looks like:
[image]

I want to fill an alert like this one:
[image]

Comment: can you share screen shot or stacktrace error?

Comment: what type of alert you are getting?

Answer (score 3):

This question does not provide enough information though. I will give you some Approaches :

**Approach 1 :**

You have to switch to alert box before you want to have interaction.

```
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
```

Then you can **proceed** further in your execution. Something like this after switching to alert :

```
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());  
alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword(username, password));
```

**Approach 2 :**

```
String username = "a";
String password = "bbbbb";
String URL = "http://" + username  + ":" + password + "@" + localhost:8015/thing/Home;
driver.get(URL);
Alert alert = driver.switchTo().alert();
alert.accept();
```

**Approach 3 :**  You may try AutoIT script. Please note that AutoIT script will work only in windows environment. However, I would not recommend you to go with this approach.

Comment: The problem is that the method authenticateUsing appears to be undefined for the alert

Comment: There is no method authenticateUsing  is present in alert interface.  There are only these methods :   void dismiss();

  void accept();

  String getText();

  void sendKeys(String keysToSend);

Comment: You can try approach 2 , it will work in my opinion.