# How to enter login/password into a browser without knowing the code of the popup?

Tags: protractor

Can anyone explain to me how to enter login/password into a browser popup without knowing the code of the popup using Protractor ?

Thank you for your help[Popup](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZElVz.png)

Comment: Your Auth popup does not looks like JavaScript popup, but OS dialog. Protractor can't control OS dialog, can only control browser related stuff.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to handle basic authentication with protractor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27234785/how-to-handle-basic-authentication-with-protractor)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `authenticateUsing` method. See the doc:
https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/Alert.html

And usage example:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/51129214/6331748